# Things to keep in mind for smooth transition from Version 1.0 to 2.0 on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, version-control, user-experience

I am planning to develop an application. As the app is quite big in size, I am planning to go for version 2.0 in few months after release of version 1.0.

I would like to know that what things I should be careful of up front. So that, when I release version 2.0, things go smooth on both development side and user experience side.

Comment: are you using core data?

Comment: Yes, I am planning to use core-data. However, I am not sure that schema  would change or not.

Comment: Just make sure to create a NEW data model, and not tinker with the existing one. You need this to migrate the data to the new datamodel if it needs changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `SVN` - Copy your first version and save it in another folder and make your changes in version 2 folder.
2. Analyze and remove your unused Design assets (like .png, etc) to reduce your app size.
3. If you have backend APIs in your version 1 app, Let's create the new APIs for version 2 development.
4. Make sure you have takes backup your DB before move version 1 to production.
5. You should not add your new updates in Version1 PROD API in DB table as well.

Answer (score 2):

1. List out things which are going in 1st version and which are going in the 2nd.(You might have already done this.)
2. The most important thing you will need to handle is the Data.. especially data created by user. If you are using database, make sure you make provision for updating it without data loss in the next version.
3. If you need to save some data like passwords, you can use `NSUserDefaults`.
4. Work with good coding practices and you will be fine.

Hope this helps.